# Isekai manhwa about 2-3 people who die from drinking too much, and wake up in a manhwa

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, female-characters

I'm trying to find this manhwa. There was two or three? (I'm not sure) people who were drinking so much that they died (I think. I'm not sure again) then they woke up, and found that they were transmitted to a manhwa. It was on TikTok.

Comment: Please help me find this manhwa its so boring right now

Comment: Was it a fantasy world? Science fiction? Men? Women? A system? Did they speak the language?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Were these people male or female? Was this in black-and-white or colour? What were the names of the characters? Were they playing drinking game? What was the setting before (modern, urban?) What was the setting in their new world (fantasy/medieval)? Was there sex/nudity/gore? Was there a villain? How did they get to their new world?

Comment: *Fantasy Bishoujo Juniku Ojisan (Life with an Ordinary Guy Who Reincarnated into a Total Fantasy Knockout)* meets some of these tropes.

Comment: It was two females drinking when they woke up they were a character in a novel one of the female lead has pink hair and thr other one has black or red hair. Sorry i forgot to put this i was really sleepy when i post this hehe

Comment: Do they explicitly reincarnate into a manhwa? Most such stories are reincarnation into a novel or game, as most manhwa are adapted from (web) novels. Do you just mean that they reincarnate into a fictional world that they had read before?